# SSH Tunnel between two VPNs

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have an ssh tunnel from my home router (R) to a VPN (A). Can I setup another tunnel from another VPN (B) to my home router (R) in a way that traffic from VPN A to VPN B will be tunneled? I'm looking for the following A <-> R <-> B.

My final goal is to have a direct port to port connection between the two IPs.

Is it possible? Can you give me some tips on how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Should be possible, do you want to forward all data from A->R->B without prejudice? Should be able to create a rule for this after the tunnel is established. Is this a stock router, or something like DDWRT?

Comment: Yes, without prejudice both ways. I have a weak version of DDWRT but it has port forwarding. What IPs do I specify in the port forwarding rule? External VPN IPs? They're shared between the whole networks.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, indeed you can, and this is one of the things a router is for (routing traffic between different networks).

If the VPN on the other end isn't set up to let you route your own subnets (most aren't, but there is a feature for it; setting it up is a little complex), you may have to do NAT between the different VPN networks so all the hosts appear to be your router when traffic goes over the VPN.

Comment: In my situation, I have no way of configuring the VPN networks. I have control only over my router but I don't see what the steps would be to make it work. 1st thing I have to open the tunnel between A and R and also B and R. Say I open it on port 443. What do I have to do on the router to make it work?

Comment: I mean I can't just put VPN's external IPs and the ports to forward. This won't work right?

Comment: Indeed it won't.  There is no mechanism for that.